# Need to convert my Windows Phone 8.1 app code to Windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I have developed an app for Windows Phone 8.1 but now I want the same app to developed in Windows phone 8.0. It is possible to do that? Is there any migration tool available or I need to develop from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't downgrade any app after you've started developing. IF you wanted to develop a WP8 as you said have to start it from the scratch. But still you can upgrade a WP8 app to WP 8.1 (For Silverlight Apps). If it's normal WinRT app you can only develop targeting 8.1 only.

For more have a look [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7a3a35e5-835e-4675-a30a-277fa056d558/cant-downgrade-project-to-80?forum=wpdevelop)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank u anonshankar :)

Answer (score 0):

You just compile the 8.0 release and upload the *:xap to the store without deleting your 8.1 *.appxupload.

Uppdate App >> Upload and describe your package(s) >> **Add new**

You might wanna consider making a phone 7 app for best coverage (7 will work for 8.0 users).